# Angular Reactive Forms - keep only one element in FormArray after submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have a FormGroup that includes FormArray.
When the user fulfills the form, he/she can dynamically add new controls. For this purpose I use FormArray.
But after the form was submitted all the controls that the user added remained on the page.
So I want to keep only one control in the FormArray after clicking the submit button.

Code is the following:

```
  workoutForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    completed: [false],
    exercises: this.fb.array([this.createExercise()])
  })

  createExercise(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      completed: [false]
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
   // Here I want to delete all elements from the exercises and to keep only one
    this.workoutForm.reset();
  }
```

**UI** (don't judge it. No CSS yet :) )

[image]

You can see there are 2 Exercise fields now. I want it to be only 1 after I clicked submit. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just solved it this way:

I added a getter for my exercises (I will need it later in my code).

```
get exercises() {
  return this.workoutForm.get('exercises') as FormArray;
}
```

Then I cleared all exercises - this removes all elements from the `FormArray`.

```
this.exercises.clear();
```

And then I added a field again

```
  addExercise() {
    this.exercises.push(this.createExercise());
  }

onSubmit() {
  ///...some code
  this.addExercise();
}
```

So the overall code looks like this:

```
workoutForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    completed: [false],
    exercises: this.fb.array([this.createExercise()])
  })

  get exercises() {
    return this.workoutForm.get('exercises') as FormArray;
  }

  createExercise(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      completed: [false]
    })
  }

  addExercise() {
    this.exercises.push(this.createExercise());
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.workoutForm.reset();
    this.exercises.clear();
    this.addExercise();
  }
```

Comment: even you could create your own array, this.excersisesArray.push({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      completed: [false]
    }) , and later update it with shift()